# Is it possible edit .CSS file while .SCSS file is not in the same root?

Tags: css, directory, sass

Something like this:

```
sass --watch style.css:(other than root directory)
//or
sass --watch (other directory than .scss file):style.scss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of `sass --help`:

```
--watch Watch files or directories for changes.
        The location of the generated CSS can be set using a colon:
          sass --watch input.sass:output.css
          sass --watch input-dir:output-dir
```

You can, there isn't any restriction. Just use the directory from where you call `sass` as the base path or an absolute path. For example:

```
sass --watch relative/path/to/a/scss/file:/absolute/path/to/a/css/file
```